# Python lambda function returns KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create simple Lambda function using Python 3.6.

The function should get a userId (my primary key in DynamoDB) in the  request query string params and returns 200 if item exist in DB, here is my lambda function

```
import boto3
import os
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  userId = event["userId"]

  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
  table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['Customers'])
  items = table.query(
  KeyConditionExpression=Key('userId').eq(userId)
  )

  return items["Items"]
```

When i am doing tests in Lambda interface it works and return the correct user however,  when trying from Postman or using API Gateway it returns the following error

```
{
"errorMessage": "'userId'",
"errorType": "KeyError",
"stackTrace": [
    [
        "/var/task/index.py",
        7,
        "lambda_handler",
        "userId = event["userId"]"
    ]
]
}
```

- What am i missing here ?
- Struggling to understand "event"  ,  documentation states its a python 
  dictionary but how can i print the result of it and actually debug the lambda 
  when called from Postman or API Gateway?

Comment: The `event` mapping doesn't seem to have a key named `'userId'`. Try `print`ing `event` to see if something is off there.

Comment: Have you tried [Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice)? It will save you a lot of the headache of setting this up.

Comment: import json then print json.dumps(event)

Comment: printing event doesn't really help,  in the Lambda console i am making tests and it returns the user however,  only from postman, browser, API Gateway test i am getting this error, even if i am returning the print of event

Comment: I tried removing all my code and just returning print(event) in the end of lambda function   , in API Gateway side in the request in the Method Request Query string i have added userId and  tested it  but it returns null

Comment: Using postman how are you passing AWS access keys ? Have you set credentials correctly to access AWS  resources?

Comment: Actually i am not passing my AWS access keys ,  i have setup a Role with a policy that allows accessing all the resources needed and attached it to the Lambda,  Postman is just another method  i have also tried from the API gateway UI and from browser itself by using the url with params

Comment: @JamZ did you ever figure out a solution? I am stuck in the exact same situation. I am able to see it work fine inside the Lambda console but as soon as I call the url with params using curl, I get the same KeyError. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `event["userId"]`, this means that sending the request payload for example

```
GET API : api/users/
Request Body payload:

{
"userId":"1234"
}
```

then above code works, Suppose you want to send userId as path parameter

```
GET API :api/user/{userId}
```

then you can access in lambda function

```
userId = (event['pathparameters']['userId'])
```

better add the print statement
print(event) and check the logs in cloudwatch logs

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me on post requests

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    data = json.loads(event["body"])
    email = data['email']
```

in case you are using the serverless framework you can also add the following code under your http event. but i dont think it is that necessary.

```
request:
  parameters:
    application/json: '{"email":"$input.params(''email'')"}'
```

Comment: Here I get `[ERROR] KeyError: 'body'`

Comment: hmm... maybe you can  `print(event)` and confirm the keys in there

Comment: I figured it out, in my lambda I am using `awslambdaric`, so already in my `handler` function `event` has the body immediately on it, i.e. you can access directly with `event['myJsonKey1']`, `event['myOtherJsonKey']` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you hadn't selected "Lambda Proxy" while creating the HTTP method. Proxy will not convert/modify the request and hence "event" will be null

Answer (score -1):

In my case my Python Lambda required a key called exclude. To resolve the issue of getting this response when calling via API Gateway, I needed to update the integration request with a mapping template:

[image: Mapping Template]